# Tab button does not insert indent PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, ide

When using PyCharm tab only indents the line if I select it first. This is not the same with VSCode which adds an indent of, I think, 4 spaces each time I press the tab key. I believe this is a bug but I have tried everything I have found and nothing seems to work.

Things I have tried:

1. Remapping the tab key to indent line (this only works if the line is selected)
2. Using Smart Tab
3. Using Use Tab Character

None of these have fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a bug, as the default behaviour is common on editors (also way before VS). It is not uncommon to make tables (e.g. on C header files, defining constants). VS took a different way. Note: in PyCharm (at least with KDE key bindings), if you select one or more lines, then Tab (and Shift-Tab) will indent/unindent the code.

But you can reproduce your desired behaviour: Go on settings/preferences, then *Keymap* menu. I recommend you to save current settings, and start a new custom setting (e.g. adding "Tab" to the name).

Then on the right of the right/bottom search field, look for actions with a key: press it, then press Tab. You see that there is an action "Tab", which links to `Tab`. Right click, and remove the key. We need this, not to conflict with the new behaviour of `Tab` (only this matter, we keep the other `Tab`).

Now we should give `Tab` the desired behaviour: On Keymap -> Editor Actions -> Indent Line or Selection (note: you can just look "Indent Line"). Here you select your new key to be Tab (you should press the `+` for such special keys).

Now the settings seems similar to VS. I'm not using it much, so e.v. you should tweak other settings. Note, on my KDE keybindings, Shift+Tab is already set as `Unindent`.

Comment: Just to let people reading this in the future know, this worked for me and indents the line on pressing tab. However, unlike VSCode, it does not add an indent at your cursor and instead just indents the line.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings ---> editor ----> code style ----> check the box for "detect and use existing file indents for editing".

Under Code style again, select Python. At the right hand side, you will see Tab size, ensure it's 4, the indent should also be 4

[image: Check attached photo]

Comment: Note: you do not answer the question. Try with your settings, and you see it will not change the behaviour. (the question is not about coding style)

Answer (score 0):

in the setting | keymap, select Windows (not Windows copy) or click reset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWgIm.png)